# How to initialize a MapView() with TomTom SDK in Xcode?

Tags: swift, swiftui, tomtom

I have installed and imported `TomTomSDKMapDisplay` into my Xcode project and am trying to display a map on a view. Following the TomTom Developer instructions, I am trying to assign my api key. Here is the link to the instructions I have been following (this is my first time attempting to make use of APIs in Xcode): https://developer.tomtom.com/ios/maps/documentation/guides/map-display/quickstart#getting-the-map

However, when `MapsDisplayService.apiKey = "ThisIsKey"` is placed in `var body: some View {`, the error

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'

is given. Where then am I supposed to write this line? Below is a screen shot of the code.

[image]

Comment: 1. Always post code as text and not as an image 2. You can’t have regular swift code like that inside a view body. You need to learn the basics about SwiftUI before using it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I’m currently doing that, but I can’t find anything on where to write code on a page that isn’t triggered by or attached to specific items on the view. Where would I edit an attribute of an imported class? I apologise for my misunderstanding

Comment: Perhaps in an `init` method or something like `onAppear`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.tomtom.com/assets/downloads/tomtom-sdks/ios/api-reference/0.29.0/TomTomSDKMapDisplay/Classes/MapsDisplayService.html), if you want to set the API key, you need to do it before a MapView can be used. As an example, this can be done in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate method.

Then in your View class, you can instantiate the MapView.

```
func application(_: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions _: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool { 
   MapsDisplayService.apiKey = “MAP_KEY” 
   […] 
   return true
}
```